# Unable to get data of Foreign key tables in same serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Order table

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    tableid=models.IntegerField()
    orderid=models.IntegerField()
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

Articles table to save articles like pizza

```
class OrderArticle(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Orders, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Articles, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # article_options = models.ManyToManyField(ArticlesOptions)
```

Article options to save extra topping or any option available

```
class OrderArticleOptions(models.Model):
    # order = models.ForeignKey(Orders, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article_option = models.ForeignKey(ArticlesOptions, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_article = models.ForeignKey(OrderArticle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

**EDIT**

Article Option table

```
class ArticlesOptions(models.Model):
    articleoptionrestaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE , blank=True, null=True)
    optionname = models.ForeignKey(ArticlesOptionsName, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="optionnames")
    min = models.IntegerField()
    max = models.IntegerField()
    choice_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.optionname)
```

So Now issue is When I try to get all data in one serialize I am not able to get . I am using this example to get

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

**EDIT**

My serilizers are

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    restaurant=RestaurantSerializer(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = ['restaurant','tableid', 'orderid', 'total_amount']

class ArticlesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order = OrderSerializer(read_only=True)
    article=ListArticleSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = OrderArticle
        fields = ['order', 'article']


class ArticlesOptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    article_option = ListCategoriesSerializer(  read_only=True)
    order_article=ArticlesSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = OrderArticleOptions
        fields = ['article_option','order_article','quantity','price']
    depth=1
```

**My view.py is**

```
class OrderedArticles(APIView):
    def get(self, request, restid):

        Options=OrderArticleOptions.objects.filter(order_article=1)
        orderserlizer=ArticlesOptionSerializer(Options , many=True)
        return Response(success_response({'orders': orderserlizer.data},
                                         "Restaurant with this all data."), status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**My JSON Response is**

```
   "article_option":{  },
        "order_article":{  
           "order":{  
              "restaurant":{  },
              "tableid":12,
              "orderid":1,
              "total_amount":"0.00"
           },
           "article":{  
              "id":1,
              "category":{  },
              "ingredient":[  ],
              "articleoptionnames":{  },
              "restaurant":{  },
              "articlename":"Article1",
              "price":"1.90",
              "pickuptax":6,
              "dineintax":21,
              "description":"This is a tekst field with more information about the product",
              "image":"/media/Article/c1.264f3b28_sxcPiqi.png"
           }
        },
```

**While I want these "article_option" to be as  child of article like   Article {article_option1, article_option2}** but its creating new objects with every new article option.

Comment: Can you please paste your serializer code and also specify which fields you cannot get?

Comment: @slider  I am getting weird result , I want to get data like  order 1 - >  article 1  - > {topping 1 , topping 2 }   while I am getting data  order1 ->  {topping1 , article1 } , {topping2 , article2}

Comment: @slider  question updated . kindly do ask if any doubt

Comment: @slider am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: yes, I was just looking at your problem. From what I understand, you want your view to return an `OrderArticle` object with `article_options` as a list under that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to return a representation of `OrderArticle` which have `ArticleOption` objects as its children. Which means you should instantiate an `ArticlesSerializer` in your view, but also modify `ArticlesSerializer` so that it includes all related `article_options` as a list (using the `source` attribute). Something like the following:

```
class ArticlesOptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    article_option = ListCategoriesSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = OrderArticleOptions
        fields = ['article_option', 'order_article', 'quantity', 'price']


class ArticlesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order = OrderSerializer(read_only=True)
    article = ListArticleSerializer(read_only=True)
    article_options = ArticlesOptionSerializer(read_only=True, source='orderarticleoptions_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = OrderArticle
        fields = ['order', 'article', 'article_options']
```

Then in your view, you should instantiate your `ArticlesSerializer` with the appropriate `OrderArticle` object:

```
class OrderedArticles(APIView):
    def get(self, request, restid):
        order_article = OrderArticle.objects.get(pk=1) # get pk/id from request
        serializer = ArticlesSerializer(order_article)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: I am getting this error   :  Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `order_article` on serializer `ArticlesOptionSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `RelatedManager` instance.
Original exception text was: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'order_article'.

Comment: @gamer That's strange because based on the models you posted, `OrderArticleOptions` has the foreign key field `order_article` so the `ArticlesOptionSerializer` should pick it up. Are you sure that is the correct model definition for `OrderArticleOptions`? You can update the `fields` in the serializer based on what is present in the model.

Comment: article_options = ArticlesOptionSerializer(read_only=True, source='orderarticleoptions_set' , many=True)     I got the issue :p.  issue was many=true in this line.

Comment: No 1 last thing I want to ask .if you don't mind.  If I want to show all orders with all articles and nested article options I have to do same scenario in order serilizer ?

Comment: @gamer Nice catch! You need `many=True` there because it's a list. As for your second question, yes, you'll have to do something similar in `OrderSerializer`.

Comment: sorry to bother you . what is best way to put data in all there tables with one api post call ?